# TF270003: Failed to copy

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

This pertains to:

- Visual Studio 2013
- Team Foundation Server 2010

Error:

> TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory \\TFSFileStore\TFSBuild\Xxx\Yyy\_PublishedWebsites\Zzz exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.

`_PublishedWebsites` does not exist.  The problem is that it isn't being created by MSBuild.  Even if I were to manually create those folders, the files don't get copied there.

We just upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013.

---

After perusing the log files, it seems as though the wrong MSBuild is being used.  It's using:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

when it should be using:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
```

Any ideas on how to get TFS to use the correct MSBuild executable?

---

I followed http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2013/10/building-visual-studio-2013-solutions.html:

> 1) Find all instances of the MSBuild activity. The activity is named as “Run MSBuild for Project” within the build templates as show below:
>
> [image]
>
> 2) Change the ToolsPath of the activity to point to the MSBuild 12.0 exe file as shown below:
>
> [image]

However ... the log in Diagnostic mode shows the following for Run MSBuild for Project:

```
Initial Property Values
    AdditionalVCOverrides = 
    CommandLineArguments = /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /tv:12.0
    Configuration = Release
    GenerateVSPropsFile = True
    LogFile = 
    LogFileDropLocation = \\Xxx\Yyy\Zzz\logs
    MaxProcesses = 1
    OutDir = E:\Builds\Xxx\Binaries
    Platform = Any CPU
    Project = E:\Builds\Xxx\Xxx.sln
    ResponseFile = 
    RunCodeAnalysis = AsConfigured
    Targets = 
    TargetsNotLogged = String[] Array
    ToolPath = 
    ToolPlatform = X86
    Verbosity = Diagnostic

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

Somehow, the `ToolPath` property that I set to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64\
```

is getting overridden and set to empty.

Comment: Have you verified that the user that msbuild is executing under actually has permission to that directory?  Generally speaking that's the #1 cause; well, other than not having enough disk space if the first place.

Comment: Yes I have. Plus, it creates the `Xxx\Yyy` folders during the build.  You would think that if it were a perms issue that it would fail way earlier in the process. Also, it worked just fine for the past year under VS2010.  All we did was upgrade to VS2013.  There's got to be some `.csproj` or `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` line missing or wrong; something to that effect is what I'm thinking.

Comment: Did you install [Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) on the build server?

Comment: @KMoraz - I installed VS2013 on the build server, which I would assume takes care of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my build definition, I ended up creating a **Sequence** variable which I called **`MSBuildToolPath`** and set its value to **`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin`**.

Still in my build definition, from there I found every **`Run MSBuild for Project`** activity and set their **`ToolPath`** property to the aforementioned **`MSBuildToolPath`** variable.

That had MSBuild *finally* using the correct version.

However, my happiness didn't last long because the next issue was that **MSBuild** couldn't locate the **`*.metaproj`** file.

After some research, we found that we could create an **Environment System Variable** of **`MSBUILDEMITSOLUTION`** and set its value to **`1`** to force the creation of that file.

Once that was done, we had a successful build where it created the **`_PublishedWebsites\Zzz`** folder and deployed to our web server ... *finally!*

Answer (score 2):

If your build process template is from an earlier version of TFS, you might need to edit your template and modify an MSBuild activity property.

If your build server is running:

Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013: Set the MSBuild activity ToolVersion property to 12.0

Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012: Set the MSBuild ToolPath property to the path to the path to MSBuild 12. In many cases, this path is either C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\ (32-bit) or C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\amd64 (64-bit). You must also install Visual Studio 2013 on the build agent.

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647548.aspx)

Comment: We are using **TFS2010**. I don't see a **MSBuild ToolVersion** property in the **Process** section of the build definition.  On the **MSBuild Arguments** property, I did the `/tv:12.0` and it still runs the `MSBuild.exe` out of the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` directory.

Comment: What is the MSBUILD Platform property set too?

Comment: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.ToolPlatform.Auto` which then the log in Diagnostic mode shows `X86`.

Comment: I updated the question with more of my troubleshooting

Comment: At what point during the build are you getting the error? "TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory \\TFSFileStore\TFSBuild\Xxx\Yyy\_PublishedWebsites\Zzz exists and that you have the appropriate permissions."

Comment: At the very end after it builds successfully. It's basically the last step.

Answer (score 0):

When you queue a new build, set a private drop location under the Parameter's Tab